# Validation Accuracy Does Not Improve in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN like AlexNet trying to predict class of the ornament. The train accuracy and loss monotonically increase and decrease respectively. But, the test accuracy fluctuates around 0.50.

I've tried to change various hyperparameters, changed batch size,used data augmentation, changed data to gray scale because its just stone pictures, added dropout, regularization, Gaussian noise, changed the unit count in dense layers but still the validation accuracy does not change.

I don't know what to do and how to improve my model. Please help me

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator (rescale = 1/255, 
                                  featurewise_center =True,
                                  shear_range= 0.2, 
                                  zoom_range=0.2, 
                                  rotation_range=90,
                                  width_shift_range=0.1,
                                  height_shift_range=0.1,
                                  fill_mode = 'nearest',
                                  vertical_flip = True,
                                  horizontal_flip=True)

training_set=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/My Drive/DATASET1/train', 
                                               target_size= (224,224),
                                               batch_size= 128,
                                               color_mode='grayscale',

                                               class_mode='categorical')

test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator ( rescale = 1/255, 
                                  featurewise_center =True,
                                  #shear_range= 0.2, 
                                  #zoom_range=0.2, 
                                  #horizontal_flip=True
                                )

test_set=test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/My Drive/DATASET1/val', 
                                               target_size= (224,224),
                                               batch_size= 48,
                                               color_mode='grayscale',
                                               class_mode='categorical')
```

```
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(224,224,1), kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding="same", activation = "relu"))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))

# Batch Normalisation before passing it to the next layer
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation = "relu"))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))

# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation = "relu"))

# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation = "relu"))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation = "relu"))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))

# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
regularizer =keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.0005)
model.add(GaussianNoise(0.1))
model.add(Dense(units = 4096, activation = "relu", kernel_regularizer = regularizer))

# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001, center=True, scale=True, beta_initializer='zeros', gamma_initializer='ones', moving_mean_initializer='zeros', moving_variance_initializer='ones', beta_regularizer=None))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
regularizer =keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.0005)
model.add(GaussianNoise(0.1))
model.add(Dense(units = 2048, activation = "relu", kernel_regularizer = regularizer ))

# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
regularizer =keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.0005)
model.add(GaussianNoise(0.1))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation = "relu", kernel_regularizer = regularizer))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())


# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(2, activation = "softmax")) #As we have two classes
```

```
Epoch 1/20
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py:716: UserWarning: This ImageDataGenerator specifies `featurewise_center`, but it hasn't been fit on any training data. Fit it first by calling `.fit(numpy_data)`.
  warnings.warn('This ImageDataGenerator specifies ')
5/5 [==============================] - 9s 2s/step - loss: 6.2275 - accuracy: 0.5244 - val_loss: 5.9162 - val_accuracy: 0.4985

Epoch 00001: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.49853, saving model to alexnet_1.h5
Epoch 2/20
5/5 [==============================] - 7s 1s/step - loss: 6.1302 - accuracy: 0.6031 - val_loss: 5.9220 - val_accuracy: 0.5103

Epoch 00002: val_accuracy improved from 0.49853 to 0.51032, saving model to alexnet_1.h5
Epoch 3/20
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 6.1390 - accuracy: 0.6250 - val_loss: 6.0433 - val_accuracy: 0.4932

Epoch 00003: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51032
Epoch 4/20
5/5 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 6.0528 - accuracy: 0.6429 - val_loss: 5.9255 - val_accuracy: 0.4985

Epoch 00004: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51032
Epoch 5/20
5/5 [==============================] - 7s 1s/step - loss: 6.0935 - accuracy: 0.6094 - val_loss: 5.9714 - val_accuracy: 0.4926

Epoch 00005: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51032
Epoch 6/20
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 6.0139 - accuracy: 0.6447 - val_loss: 5.5711 - val_accuracy: 0.4932

Epoch 00006: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51032
Epoch 7/20
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 6.0250 - accuracy: 0.6353 - val_loss: 5.9171 - val_accuracy: 0.5133

Epoch 00007: val_accuracy improved from 0.51032 to 0.51327, saving model to alexnet_1.h5
Epoch 8/20
5/5 [==============================] - 7s 1s/step - loss: 6.0012 - accuracy: 0.6422 - val_loss: 6.0526 - val_accuracy: 0.4749

Epoch 00008: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 9/20
5/5 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 5.9814 - accuracy: 0.6635 - val_loss: 5.4898 - val_accuracy: 0.4966

Epoch 00009: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 10/20
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 906ms/step - loss: 5.9613 - accuracy: 0.6769 - val_loss: 6.1255 - val_accuracy: 0.4956

Epoch 00010: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 11/20
5/5 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 5.9888 - accuracy: 0.6484 - val_loss: 6.2377 - val_accuracy: 0.4956

Epoch 00011: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 12/20
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 6.0045 - accuracy: 0.6767 - val_loss: 5.4328 - val_accuracy: 0.4932

Epoch 00012: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 13/20
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 5.9569 - accuracy: 0.6654 - val_loss: 5.9874 - val_accuracy: 0.4985

Epoch 00013: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 14/20
5/5 [==============================] - 7s 1s/step - loss: 5.8978 - accuracy: 0.6859 - val_loss: 6.2074 - val_accuracy: 0.4897

Epoch 00014: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 15/20
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 6.0063 - accuracy: 0.6792 - val_loss: 5.3235 - val_accuracy: 0.4966

Epoch 00015: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 16/20
5/5 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 5.8966 - accuracy: 0.7068 - val_loss: 6.1324 - val_accuracy: 0.5015

Epoch 00016: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 17/20
5/5 [==============================] - 7s 1s/step - loss: 5.9352 - accuracy: 0.6562 - val_loss: 6.2356 - val_accuracy: 0.4867

Epoch 00017: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 18/20
5/5 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 5.9475 - accuracy: 0.6391 - val_loss: 7.9573 - val_accuracy: 0.4966

Epoch 00018: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 19/20
5/5 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 5.9627 - accuracy: 0.6898 - val_loss: 6.0916 - val_accuracy: 0.4985

Epoch 00019: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
Epoch 20/20
5/5 [==============================] - 6s 1s/step - loss: 5.8621 - accuracy: 0.6974 - val_loss: 6.3277 - val_accuracy: 0.4926

Epoch 00020: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.51327
```

Comment: Not sure since you haven't given any examples from your data, but it might be that your model is too complex for the task at hand. In similar problems there is usually no need for the dense layers. Have you tried using a (much) smaller fully convolutional network?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to reduce size of both conv layers and fully connected layers and it worked better. But even though the validation accuracy increased up to 0.91, validation accuracy and validation loss still fluctuates a lot. The graphs looks weird compared to training ones.

Comment: @ornamentiscrime, Can you please update your question with the modified code. Also, please share the plots of Training and Validation, Accuracy and Loss, so that we can understand the problem exactly. Thanks!

Comment: @ornamentiscrime, Is your issue resolved? If not, You can try Shuffling the Data using `shuffle = True` in `flow_from_directory` method. Also, please add the code corresponding to `model.compile` and `model.fit`, so that we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you said in Output layer, you have 2 classes, which indicates this model is for binary classification-(0,1). For this classification, you need to define output layer as below:

`model.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))`

Along with `class_mode='binary'` and `binary_crossentropy` loss function in your model.
I have removed `BatchNormalization()` and `Dropout()` to test because we are already using `data augmentation` with large dataset.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16, input_shape=(224,224,1), kernel_size=(3,3),  activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), ))

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3),   activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), ))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = "relu" ))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")) #As we have two classes
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_set, epochs =50, validation_data=test_set)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 45/50
16/16 [==============================] - 23s 1s/step - loss: 0.5665 - accuracy: 0.7180 - val_loss: 0.5676 - val_accuracy: 0.6960
Epoch 46/50
16/16 [==============================] - 22s 1s/step - loss: 0.5678 - accuracy: 0.7120 - val_loss: 0.5528 - val_accuracy: 0.7160
Epoch 47/50
16/16 [==============================] - 22s 1s/step - loss: 0.5524 - accuracy: 0.7305 - val_loss: 0.5584 - val_accuracy: 0.7060
Epoch 48/50
16/16 [==============================] - 23s 1s/step - loss: 0.5651 - accuracy: 0.7100 - val_loss: 0.5554 - val_accuracy: 0.7120
Epoch 49/50
16/16 [==============================] - 22s 1s/step - loss: 0.5587 - accuracy: 0.7145 - val_loss: 0.5604 - val_accuracy: 0.7120
Epoch 50/50
16/16 [==============================] - 22s 1s/step - loss: 0.5522 - accuracy: 0.7265 - val_loss: 0.5281 - val_accuracy: 0.7260
```

You can find the details to overcome from overfitting problem and optimize the model better by following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit#training_procedure) reference.